# Is there a global error handling location in WCF comparable to Global.asax's Application_Error in ASP.Net?

Tags: wcf, exception

I'm creating a WCF service and I need to implement error handling.   In ASP.NET it was possible to centralize error handling in the `Application_Error` event handler in `global.asax`.

Is there a comparable solution for WCF other than ASP.NET compatibility mode? I cannot use `AspNetCompatibilityEnabled` because the transport is not guaranteed to be HTTP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a global exception handler for a WCF Services?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747011/how-do-i-create-a-global-exception-handler-for-a-wcf-services)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How do I create a global exception handler for a WCF Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747011/how-do-i-create-a-global-exception-handler-for-a-wcf-services)