# What is the easiest way to log exceptions from a WCF service to a the Windows Event Log?

Tags: wcf, exception

I want to log all exceptions (including serialization exception stack traces) in a WCF server to the Windows Event Log (log4net logging would also be acceptable).

What is the easiest way to do this?

Specifically all errors in serialization, in the service itself, etc.  Right now I'm using tracing to get serialization errors during development.  Tracing was the only way I could find out what object was actually have a problem with serialization.  See [Quickly finding WCF Serialization/Deserialization Issues](http://coab.wordpress.com/2010/03/08/quickly-finding-wcf-serializationdeserialization-issues/) for an example of getting the serialization stack trace.

I can handle errors in the service code itself.  However, errors in the WCF machinery don't propagate to my service code (like serialization errors).

I don't need to send the errors to the client.

I just want to get the errors into one location (like the Event Log).

Right now (from my research) it appears that the [IErrorHandler Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx) with some custom code might be the best way to proceed.  Will using the IErrorHandling interace catch the serialization exceptions?

Edit:
This may be the answer I'm looking for:
[How do I create a global exception handler for a WCF Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747011/how-do-i-create-a-global-exception-handler-for-a-wcf-services)

I'd just like a confirmation that this will catch serialization errors and more importantly *the details* of those errors, also.

More Info:
[How do I create a global exception handler for a WCF Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747011/how-do-i-create-a-global-exception-handler-for-a-wcf-services)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, IErrorHandler will also catch serialization exceptions. You will get all information stored in the exception. Whether or not this enough detail for you, I can't say.

Note that there may be client-side errors (serialization and others) which will never make it to the server. You will not see those with the IErrorHandler.

Comment: Client side is fine.  So far that's been easy to fix. The hard issues are the exception errors buried deep in WCF that I wasn't able to get to without tracing).

Comment: @telewin do you know if it's possible to capture an exception when for example, the client sends a string to a int32 field? In my tests this seams impossible but you might know better than me