# Access Denied Error for a method in web service

Tags: wcf, web-services, visual-studio-2008

I have a webservice that works perfectly from localhost but when I hosted it on the testing server I get an error on one of the methods. I am using wsHttp Binding. everything else works fine on the client side except for this method. This is the error that I am getting

client error:

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException: Access is denied.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

Server error:

```
namespace.Service Error: 10001 : Error occurred in methodname(). 
 System.Security.SecurityException: The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  Inaccessible logs: Security.
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.FindSourceRegistration(String source, String machineName, Boolean readOnly)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists(String source, String machineName)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.VerifyAndCreateSource(String sourceName, String currentMachineName)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEvent(EventInstance instance, Byte[] data, Object[] values)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEvent(EventInstance instance, Object[] values)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener.TraceEvent(TraceEventCache eventCache, String source, TraceEventType severity, Int32 id, String format, Object[] args)
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType eventType, Int32 id, String format, Object[] args)
   at AutoWatch.Entity.WcfService.TrackingService.UpdateIncidentStatusHistory(Int64 incidentId, String status, String username, String comment, Boolean SuspectFaultyUnit) in C:\..servicename.cs:line 566
   at AutoWatch.Entity.WcfService.TrackingService.GetNewIncidentMessage(String username) in C:\..servicename.cs:line 444
```

The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
MyComputer

I added in the error I am getting on the server.
Is it possible I am getting this error because the service cannot write to the event log?

Please help.

Comment: What exactly are you doing in that method?

Comment: it just retrieves some information from the database

Comment: i have added in the error from the server to my post. i didnt have access to the server previously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that account running your process where the service is hosted has access rights to the database. For example in case of IIS the account running the application pool where the service is hosted must have login to database server and it must have permissions to do all necessary operations in your database.

Edit:

The server stack trace looks quite straightforward. You have a problem with writing to Windows Event Log! It cannot find source you requested and it doesn't have permission to create it.

Comment: the account does have access to the database. other methods retrieve data with no problems its just one that has a problem. this one method on the client side is using a background worker could that be a problem?

Comment: Turn on wcf tracing on both client and server and check for error details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Comment: This is not related to your former exception and it mostly means that none of your method should work. You should have enough information to check your configuration files and find what is causing this problem.

Comment: the error is the same thing that i have posted on my initial post

Comment: ok i managed to find the fault..... i spent an entire week trying to figure this out and it was such a silly mistake i honestly feel like kicking myself...... i forgot to insert a new row on the test database thats why it kept throwing the error because datamodel couldn't find the row...... damn i feel so stupid now .....thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I tried to use the following statement in a Web Method of a WCF Service:

```
string myTypeName = typeof(ErrorHandlerBehavior).AssemblyQualifiedName;
```

where ErrorHandlerBehavior derives from BehaviorExtensionElement.

The line works well when I test the service on my localhost. On the web, the call of the containing method raises the Exception "Access is denied".

In this case, I guess that the cause was that my IP does not allow the creation of a BehaviourExtensionElement in a Partially Trusted environment (my service is in a shared hosting environment).

Finally, I succeded following the first mechanism described at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/configuring-and-extending-the-runtime-with-behaviors about Service Behaviors:

"Using an attribute on the service class. When a ServiceHost is constructed, the ServiceHost implementation uses reflection to discover the set of attributes on the type of the service. If any of those attributes are implementations of IServiceBehavior, they are added to the behaviors collection on ServiceDescription. This allows those behaviors to participate in the construction of the service run time."

I just modified the derivation (no other modification required):

```
public class ErrorServiceBehavior : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
{ ... }
```

and use the class as Attribute of my service:

```
[ErrorServiceBehavior()]
public partial class MyService : IMyService
{...}
```

No other modification required. Check the original sample at [How do I create a global exception handler for a WCF Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747011/how-do-i-create-a-global-exception-handler-for-a-wcf-services).