# WCF invoking service fail

Tags: .net, wcf, iis

I was able to call it in my own server and it works but the problem occurs when I host wcf service in IIS. The details of this error are as follows...

> Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline
>   or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the
>   proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for
>   more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring
>   to default configuration, or refreshing the service.
>
> Stack Trace Error Details
>
> The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.
>   For more information about the error, either turn on
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute
>   or from the `<serviceDebug>` configuration behavior) on the server in
>   order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on
>   tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and
>   inspect the server trace logs.
>
> Server stack trace:
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message
>   reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version,
>   FaultConverter faultConverter)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:
>   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)
>   at IUserService.GetUser(String UserID)
>   at UserServiceClient.GetUser(String UserID)

Here are the source codes:

1. app.config file from wcfservicelirbrary

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <configuration>

   <system.web>
   <compilation debug="true" />
   </system.web>
     <system.serviceModel>
       <services>
         <service name="UserServiceLibrary.UserService">
           <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding"      contract="UserServiceLibrary.IUserService">
             <identity>
               <dns value="localhost" />
             </identity>
           </endpoint>
           <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
           <host>
             <baseAddresses>
               <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/UserServiceLibrary/UserService/" />
             </baseAddresses>
           </host>
         </service>
       </services>
       <behaviors>
         <serviceBehaviors>
           <behavior>
             <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
             <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
           </behavior>
         </serviceBehaviors>
       </behaviors>
     </system.serviceModel>        
   </configuration>
   ```
2. Web config file from WCF Website Host

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>

     <system.web>
       <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
     </system.web>
     <system.serviceModel>
       <services>
         <service name="UserServiceLibrary.UserService">
          <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
     contract="IMetadataExchange" />
          <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
     contract="UserServiceLibrary.IUserService" />
          <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="UserServiceLibrary.IUserService" />
         </service>
       </services>
       <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior>

            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>

             <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          </behavior>
         </serviceBehaviors>
       </behaviors>
       <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
   </system.serviceModel>
   <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
   </system.webServer>  
   </configuration>
   ```

Comment: First, go to the server and apply the following configuration updates:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.includeexceptiondetailinfaults.aspx

Comment: Also take a look at `UserServiceClient.GetUser(String UserID)` - that's where the exception originally occurred.  Post your code and any additional information you get from dotnetnate's suggestion for better answers :)

Comment: Above are the source codes of my configuration. Please check it. thz.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that account running your process where the service is hosted has access rights to the database. For example in case of IIS the account running the application pool where the service is hosted must have login to database server and it must have permissions to do all necessary operations in your database.

Comment: Copied the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594001/access-denied-error-for-a-method-in-web-service

Answer (score 1):

As usual with WCF errors, the key is most likely right at the bottom of the stack trace:

`UserServiceClient.GetUser(String UserID)`

This was what caused the error in the first place.

To check, if you have access to the server, try attaching a Visual Studio debugger to the IIS service (usually `w3wp.exe`) that hosts your WCF code. (Do this though Debug | Attach to Process...; you'll need be running with Administrator privileges, and check "on" the "View processes from all users" option).

If you don't have direct access to attach a debugger to the service but can tweak the configuration file for the service, then try the WCF diagnostic traces (documented on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx)). This lets you create logs that can be viewed with the Service Trace Viewer - you should be able to find much more information on the exception very easily using this.

A hunch: is `UserID` null, by any chance? If so, and you're not expecting it to be, has the service contract changed recently? Adding `System.Runtime.Serialization` to the diagnostic trace for the Service Viewer can bring up some more information on that: details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd788183%28v=bts.70%29.aspx).

Comment: According to the service trace viewer, I got these error messages
 1. The body of the message cannot be read because it is empty.
 2. There was no channel that could accept the message with action 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/transfer/Get'.
 3. Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0'.

Comment: Ahh, the last one sounds like your problem; my guess would be that IIS is misconfigured on your server. Do any other ASP.NET 4 applications work? If so, check the credentials for the application pool for the service, as it sounds like it's not able to initialize because its credentials aren't correct.

Comment: @JeremyMcGee you were right.. it was the user permission for me on the application pool. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Best practices with WCF,

1. Make sure WCF project url along with Virtual directory is showing up without errors, and could generate proxy ( svcutil followed by hyperlink)

2 Once WCF is fine, in Client project, In ServiceReferences, choose CONFIGURE services with this above URL, 
3. That should generate proxy, if its attached to source control like TFS, please make sure to check in  - delete mode checkins also, ALONG with newly generated files ( show hidden files in the project)

1. Click on Reference.cs --> do a acid test to verify your new datacontract or datamember fields are generated, that confirms service is Upto Date

All those nasty WCF references error tough to solve, but regenerating may give relief some times...

Answer (score 0):

Problem :- I had the same problem with hosted WCF service on one of our windows servers. Application was unable to connect with the service.

Solution :- Had to reset app/pool of WCF service

Thanks