# How to log error 500 in wcf applications

Tags: wcf

We all are know some time we will get 500 error while trying to hit wcf url. for example if pass string value to integer parameter it will throw 500 error as request error. my question is how to log, this kind error in some file? because this will not reach our actual end point class coding right? so how to log this error in some file? 
Any Help?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to log these on the server size, you should configure WCF tracing and use SvcTraceViewer to analyze the logs. More details on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx.

Comment: i know tracing is one way. any other machinism? trace will log 500 error?

Comment: more specific how to log error that before reaching service class code? how to log exception happens between iis request and before executing this request by our wcf?

Comment: This SO question has links to articles describing installing unhandled exception handlers in WCF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747011/how-do-i-create-a-global-exception-handler-for-a-wcf-services.

Comment: the link example tells how to log unhandled expection inside service class . but my question is how to log errors that is happening out of service class? for example i have some data contract object, while user sends request as xml dotnet framework will try to convert that xml to datacontract . in this conversion if error occurs service will throw 500 error right? how to log this kind of errors. i think it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I may very well be wrong here - but if the client is supplying the wrong parameters to a web method, that would be a 404 as no method matches the incoming request?

I would say it's the clients job to send the right data to the right function, and to handle failures appropriately (an EndPointNotFoundException perhaps)

Comment: This is not necessarily so: the client may specify an existing operation but the operation contract might be broken by the client (e.g. wrong parameter format).

Comment: neil thompson you got it wrong it seems. marcin hoppen you r right. so while we pass wrong value format it will not reach to endpoint code right? so this is throwing 500 error. more specific how to log error that before reaching service class code?

Comment: @NeilThompson is right. If the operation contract is indeed broken by the client, then that's a client issue, not a server issue. The server should say "sorry client, but you got this wrong, and it will REMAIN wrong as long as you won't communicate with me the way it's intended to. Here's a **400** error status."