# Unable to capture fault exception in client WCF app

Tags: wcf

I'm consuming a web service made in java using WCF and I'm unable to capture a fault exception. Everytime I send soap request to service I also receive a regular exception says:

> An unsecured error or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner fault exception for the fault code and detail.

When I get into the inner exception, there is only string with the name of fault object type (which is the type I have in created from wsdl proxy classes btw) and there is no way to see what is inside. I'm also using fiddler to see the request I'm sending and the response from the web service. That's actually the only way to see the error message from it. What I need to do is to capture this message in my application code. I tried to catch the FaultException in my code with no luck (it's not even hitting it). I will appreciate any help

```
        try {
            client.Open();
            SkrytkaReference.OdpowiedzSkrytkiTyp response = new SkrytkaReference.OdpowiedzSkrytkiTyp();

            SkrytkaReference.DokumentTyp dokument = new SkrytkaReference.DokumentTyp();

            dokument.nazwaPliku = model.Dokument.nazwaPliku;
            dokument.typPliku = model.Dokument.typPliku;
            dokument.zawartosc = model.Dokument.zawartosc;

            response = client.nadaj(model.IdentyfikatorPodmiotu, model.AdresSkrytki, model.AdresOdpowiedzi, true, model.DaneDodatkowe, dokument);
            /// abcprospzoo/Domyślna-1504592390539
            client.Close();
        }

        catch (FaultException<SkrytkaReference.WyjatekTyp> faultex) {
            var msgFault = faultex.CreateMessageFault();

            if (msgFault.HasDetail) {
                var detailNode = msgFault.GetDetail<XmlElement>();
            }
        }
```

Comment: have you tried a global error handler for your WCF?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747011/how-do-i-create-a-global-exception-handler-for-a-wcf-services

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already added something like client message inspector as behavior to my client class instance and I can see it goes into BeforeSendRequest method but it's not going into AfterReceiveReply method. I've also added IErrorHandler service as you said but it's not working as well :/ Looks like I can't even catch the response from the service. It goes straight away to exception and gives an error about unsecured or incorrectly secured fault error

Comment: I've seen those errors for a) TLS 1.2 not being used by client (required by server). or b) handshaking/authentication certificate is missing/expired/not permitted for the IIS account.  Check your NT Event logs. Sometimes, they contain better/more-detailed messages.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got this working. In case someone else has similar issue, here's a fix that resolved my problem:
[link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/16de05ed-3776-40e5-b576-139603e4b374/the-incoming-message-was-signed-with-a-token-which-was-different-from-what-used-to-encrypt-the-body?forum=wcf)

It's in nuronce's reply. The solution removes security from incomming service responses. From now I can capture service responses and faults (in regular FaultException) in my c# code